# sql query to get the count of duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables say Students and Class

### Student

St_ID int,
St_Name nvarchar(100)

### Class

Cl_ID int,
Cl_Name nvarchar(100).

I want to get duplicate name of students (and count) from each class
how can I write the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have foreign key `CL_ID` from `Class` table in `Student` table,

```
Select cl.CL_ID, st.St_Name, COUNT(st.St_ID)
From Student st
    Inner Join Class cl On st.CL_ID = cl.CL_ID
Group By cl.CL_ID, st.St_Name
Having COUNT(st.St_ID) > 1
```

Comment: I would assume he has a third table to link this, since a class probably has more then one student and a student probably attends more then one class.

Comment: @icemanind: Then, in that case, he'll just need to add one more join. But the fundamental of solution remains same.

Comment: Yeah you got this one. I'm going to delete my answer.